# Designing one to many relationships in an azure mobile app using entity framework code first

Tags: android, .net, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-mobile-services

I have an android app that has users and they can upload none to many videos.
To tie this together ive built two classes.In my mobile app .Net backend
From which i have scaffolded table controllers.

```html
public class Video : EntityData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Available { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string ProfileID { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    }
    public class Profile:EntityData
    {

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        //navigation property
        public ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    
    }
```

My issue is how to model this client object in my android application so that i can perfom basic C.R.U.D activities on the tables in question.So that i can easily insert items into the database using the mobile apps android client library for calling controller actions.

```html
public class Profile{
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("username")
    private String Username;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("location")
    private String Location ;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("bio")
    private String Bio;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("url")
    private String Url;

    public Profile(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Username = "To be Set";
        this.Location = "To be Set";
        this.Bio = "To be Set";
    }

    public Profile(){
    }

    public Profile(String id,String userName, String location, String bi) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Username = userName;
        this.Location = location;
        this.Bio = bi;
    }
    .........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Apps does not support tightly coupled tables.

This means you model your client with two distinct tables, connected maybe only by an Id.  You then treat them as distinct tables.

Comment: Thanks Adrian,For example u mean have two independent tables with an arbitrary field in videos that stores the profileId. And filter results from the video table that matches the profile Id yes?What kind of database would this be called then?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  The idea is that the tables are loosely coupled - you can update one without updating the other.  (and yes, I agree this is not ideal).